# Python time between x and y run code. And no code if time between xy

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

Im gonna try and explain to the best of my efforts.
Script im running is below.

I want to include something that will make the pir sensor not do anything between the hours of 24:00 and 05:00. But the button should work at those times regardless.

Also i want to be able to send different colors at certain times of the day.
So that if its between 8pm and 11 pm it will give this code to the lights: {"on":true,"bri":255,"sat":80,"hue":357}

There will be 4 colors in total. I have tried defining the command called with command(): and the colors but im at a standstill here.

Can anyone help me with this? I do really hope i made myself clear here, but fire away if anything is unclear.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")

from phue import Bridge
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
print 'Waiting for network...'
time.sleep(30)
print 'The wait is over. It\'s showtime!'
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN) #Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Read output from button.
b=Bridge('192.168.1.47')
try:
    b.connect()
except ImportError:
    print "Import error occurred!"
print "Connected to Hue bridge!"

lightson=b.get_light(2, "on")
if lightson: print "Lights are already on."
print 'Entering infinite loop...'

light_on_delay = 15  # time in min for light to stay on when button pressed
button_pressed = 0

while True:
# check for button press
input_state = GPIO.input(18)
if input_state == False:
    print('Button Pressed')
    end = (light_on_delay * 1) + time.time()
    button_pressed = 1
    command =  {"on" : True, "bri" : 255, "sat" : 0, "hue" : 0}
    b.set_group(2, command)
    lightson=True
    print('Lights are on for 15 minutes')    

# check if button has been pressed if it has check to see if time is up
if button_pressed == 1:
    if time.time() > end:
        button_pressed = 0

else:

    i=GPIO.input(4)
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.now().time()
    if (timestamp < offstarttime and timestamp > offendtime):
    if i==0:            #When output from motion sensor is LOW
        print ('No movement detected - Turning lights off')
        b.set_group(2, 'on', False) 
        lightson=False
        print ('Lights are off')
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:               #When output from motion sensor is HIGH
        print ('Movement detected - Turning lights on')
        command =  {"on" : True, "bri" : 255, "sat" : 0, "hue" : 0}
        b.set_group(2, command)
        lightson=True
        print ('Lights are on.')
        time.sleep(5)    

# added delay to prevent program using 100% cpu time.
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Add your python script to `sudo` `crontab`. You have to ensure, that bot python and python script paths are available tor pi user.

Comment: No no. Thats not what i mean. This script runs all the time, so i need to encorporate some code into it that at certain hours of the day the command =  {"on" : True, "bri" : 255, "sat" : 0, "hue" : 0} bit of the code changes to adjust brightess, sat, and hue. Also at certain hours of the day the hue motion sensor should be disabled.

Comment: Done. Tag added.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a time check using datetime module at the start of each iteration to conditionally set your command dictionary and run your PIR code if between certain hours. The button logic code should be run outside of the if blocks to make sure it always works

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    # Check to see if it is 5am or later
    if now.hour >= 5:
        # PIR sensor code here
        print("PIR sensor should work now")

    # Check to see if between 8pm and 11pm
    if now.hour >= 20 and now.hour <= 23:
        # Configure command dictionary for specific hours
        command = {"on": True,"bri": 255,"sat": 80,"hue": 357}
    else:
        # Configure command dictionary for regular hours
        command = {"on": False}

    # Rest of your code including button logic
```